# Compute the derivative $ \frac{d}{dR}\iiint_{\{(x,y,z)\in\textbf{R}^3: \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \leq R\}}f(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz. $

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let the function f and its first-order partial derivatives be continuous in $\textbf{R}^3$.  Suppose that 
$$ 
\iiint_{\textbf{R}^3}|f(x,y,z)|\,dx\,dy\,dz < \infty.
$$
Compute the derivative 
$$
\frac{d}{dR}\iiint_{\{(x,y,z)\in\textbf{R}^3: 
\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \leq R\}}f(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz.
$$
with the derivative given in terms of a surface integral.

Converting to spherical coordinates I found that
$$
\frac{d}{dR}\iiint_D f(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz =
\frac{d}{dR} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \int_0^R f(r,\theta,\phi)\;r^2 \sin(\phi)\,dr\,d\phi\,d\theta.
$$
My next step was
$$
\frac{d}{dR} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \int_0^R f(r,\theta,\phi)\;r^2 \sin(\phi)\,dr\,d\phi\,d\theta=
 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \frac{d}{dR}\int_0^R f(r,\theta,\phi)\;r^2 \sin(\phi)\,dr\,d\phi\,d\theta.
$$
In general, are you allowed to move the derivative through the  outside integrals?  Why?  My final step was
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \frac{d}{dR}\int_0^R f(r,\theta,\phi)\;r^2 \sin(\phi)\,dr\,d\phi\,d\theta=
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi f(R,\theta,\phi)R^2 \sin(\phi)\,d\phi\,d\theta=
\iint_{S(R)}f(R,\theta,\phi)R^2\;dS \;\;\;\text{ where }\;\;\; dS=\sin(\phi)\,d\phi\,d\theta,\;\; S(R) \text{ is the sphere of radius R.}
$$
Is this correct?  Is there a better way of doing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In general moving the derivative in or outside an integral is not mathematically valid, but in your case you can. It makes no difference since the integrals with respect to $\phi$ and $\theta$ are not dependant on $R$, thus differentiating the results of these integrals with respect to $R$ will yield $0$.